# ERROR: could not load library ~/orafce.so: ~/orafce.so: undefined symbol: pq_sendbyte SQL state: XX000

Tags: postgresql, orafce

Im trying to enable `Orafce(3.7.1-1)` extension on my `postgress11 (11.2-2)`

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04

- The extension is already available in the database , and is listed if I run the following command :

```
select *  from pg_catalog.pg_available_extensions
```

- However when I try running the following command, I see error below.

```
create extension orafce with schema vias;

> Error>

    ERROR: could not load library "/home/vias/path/pg11/lib/postgresql/orafce.so": /home/vias/path/pg11/lib/postgresql/orafce.so: undefined symbol: pq_sendbyte SQL state: XX000
```

Im really stuck... please advice

Comment: Thanks for helping me out on the editing... still anyone out there can assist me on the question

Answer (score 0):

Recompile the extension for Postgres 11, it's likely compiled for Postgres 10